# UITableViewCell Auto Sizing Issue Swift

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uistoryboard

This is the custom `UITableViewCell` I've designed In a `xib`. The selected element is a `UILabel`, which is required to be expand with respect to amount of text. 
In storyboard cell each element has a constant height with spacing.

[image]

Here's the code that I have in a `UITableViewController`:

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
private var exampleContent = ["This is a short text.", "This is another text, and it is a little bit longer.", "Wow, this text is really very very long! I hope it can be read completely! Luckily, we are using automatic row height!, Wow, this text is really very very long! I hope it can be read completely! Luckily, we are using automatic row height!"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 224.0
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("DescriptionOnlyCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! DescriptionOnlyCell
    cell.label.numberOfLines = 0
    cell.label.text = exampleContent[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return exampleContent.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Output of the code is same exactly as the storyboard cell, no dynamic resizing.

I've read a few threads on stackover and most of them explains same like the code posted above. Though I suspect there's some issue with the storyboard constraints. Any hint would be really helpful.

Comment: Instead of setting the constant height values for your labels, set the top and the bottom spacing constraints for all elements and remove height constraints or set their priority lower.

Comment: Can you please check whether you have given any custom height in Tableviewcell Attribute inspector

Comment: @AnveshTokala There's no row height in the attribute inspector. But in the code, I've deleted that too.

Comment: @livenplay Your solution seems to be working, I removed height constraints for all `UILabel` and managed the content hugging properties of `UILabel` elements, and it's started to expand.

Comment: @livenplay I you will post this as an answer, I'd definitely accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setting the constant height values for your labels, set the top and the bottom spacing constraints for all elements and remove height constraints or set their priority lower.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following for the selected label :

> 1. Set number of lines = 0
> 2. Set lineBreak mode = WordWrap
> 3. Set height constraint to >= 15

I am relying on the info you shared that vertical spacing for all UI components is set.

Comment: I've got those three already, Issue is elsewhere, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this would fix your resizing.

```
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    tableView.layoutIfNeeded()

}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the issue!